# Post Request with Button Click

Tags: swiftui

I build simple login screen with [FakeAPI](https://fakeapi.platzi.com/en/rest/users/)

After button clicked, I want to fetch data and go to **HomeView** screen.

It works with this but runs the code and make request 7-8 times;

```
NavigationLink(destination: HomeView(argument: loginRequestViewModel.getData(email: email, password: password))){
    HStack {
        Text("Login")
            .font(.callout)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .frame(height: 60)
            .background(.black)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .cornerRadius(10)
    }.foregroundColor(Color("themeTextGray"))
}
```

I tried this, works only once but I have no idea where to add NavigationLink in it.

```
Button("Login"){
    loginRequestViewModel.getData(email: email, password: password)
} .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    .frame(height: 60)
    .background(.black)
    .foregroundColor(.white)
    .cornerRadius(10)
```

*Note: **loginRequestViewModel.getData** asks for email and password and return accessToken and refreshToken. I can fetch them correctly.*

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution with `NavigationStack`

```swift
@State private var path = NavigationPath()
...

var body: some View {
    NavigationStack(path: $path) {
        Button {
            Task {
                let token = await viewModel.getData(email: email, password: password)
                path.append(token)
            }
        } label: {
            Text("Login")
        }
        .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { token in
            //Put destination view here
            //E.g: HomeView(argument: token)
        }
    }
}
```

In case you still want to use `NavigationLink` (which deprecated in iOS 16.0) you can do it this way

```swift
@State var trigger: Bool?
...

var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        Button {
            Task {
                await viewModel.getData(email: email, password: password)
                trigger = true
            }
        } label: {
            Text("Login")
        }
        .background {
            NavigationLink("", destination: HomeView(argument: viewModel.token), tag: true, selection: $trigger)
                .hidden()
        }
    }
}
```